# how to implement multiple items counter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to handle the count of multiple items with Js

1) what I want is when clicking on plus or minus sign , the counter number next to it updates ;
2) considering that by clicking on add room another room is added to the list and its title should change to for example in this case to (Room two);

this is my js code

```
 $(".Room-Plus-Btn").click(function () {
        Room_item=$(".Room").html()
        $(".Room-Counter-Items").append(Room_item)
    })
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="Room-Counter-Hotel-pge py-3 pr-3 col-12">

<div class="Room-Indicator">

</div>
<div class="Room-Counter-Items">
    <!--Room Item-->
    <div class="Room">
        <div class="col-12 mt-1 mb-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <p class="Room-Number"> Room one</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5"></div>
                <div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="Room-Age">
                        adult
                    </span>
                    <span class="Room-Age-Range">
                    (more than 12)
                </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 Room-Counter-Btns">
                    <button class="Btn Room-Plus">
                        <i class="fa text-grey fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                    <span class="Room-Count">0</span>
                    <button class="Btn Room-Minus">
                        <i class="fa text-grey fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 my-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="Room-Age">
                        kid
                    </span>
                    <span class="Room-Age-Range">
                    (0 to 12)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 Room-Counter-Btns">
                    <button class="Btn Room-Plus">
                        <i class="fa text-grey fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                    <span class="Room-Count">0</span>
                    <button class="Btn Room-Minus">
                        <i class="fa  text-grey fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-3 w-75">
</div>
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <button class="Room-Plus-Btn">add room</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you write the minimum code, removing the useless html, you will find the answer by yourself. and why adding the html in js? just use a variable.

Comment: I did remove the html in js and used a variable thanks ! but what now ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mohammad and welcome to StackOverflow! I hope this program shows you one way you can solve your problem

```js
const counter = (name = "", init = 0) =>
{ let value = init
  const update = f => event =>
    (value = f(value), input.value = value)
  const elem = document.createElement("div")
  const inc = document.createElement("button")
  const dec = document.createElement("button")
  const input = document.createElement("input")
  inc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("+"))
  inc.onclick = update(x => x + 1)
  dec.appendChild(document.createTextNode("-"))
  dec.onclick = update(x => x - 1)
  input.name = name
  input.disabled = true
  input.value = value
  elem.appendChild(inc)
  elem.appendChild(dec)
  elem.appendChild(input)
  return elem
}

document.body.appendChild(counter("a"))      // <input name="a" value="0">
document.body.appendChild(counter("b", 3))   // <input name="b" value="3">
document.body.appendChild(counter("c", 5))   // <input name="c" value="5">
```

Breaking down the problem into smaller parts makes it so we don't have to repeat ourselves so much!

```js
const makeButton = (text = "", onclick = event => null) =>
{ const b = document.createElement("button")
  b.onclick = onclick
  b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
  return b
}

const makeInput = (name = "", value = "") =>
{ const i = document.createElement("input")
  i.name = name
  i.value = value
  return i
}

const counter = (name = "", value = 0) =>
{ const elem = document.createElement("div")
  const input = makeInput(name, value)
  const update = f => event =>
    (value = f(value), input.value = value)
  
  input.disabled = true
  elem.appendChild(makeButton("+", update(x => x + 1)))
  elem.appendChild(makeButton("-", update(x => x - 1)))
  elem.appendChild(input)
  return elem
}

document.body.appendChild(counter("a"))      // <input name="a" value="0">
document.body.appendChild(counter("b", 3))   // <input name="b" value="3">
document.body.appendChild(counter("c", 5))   // <input name="c" value="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid the minus sign '-' in your class name.

```
$(".Room-Plus").click(function () {
     Room_Count= parseInt( $(".Room-Count").html() )+1;
    $(".Room-Count").html(Room_Count) ;
})
```

"Thank you" answer sound good regarding your second request.